# how to fix setImageValue in PHPWord which doesnt seems to work properly

Tags: phpword

Hii I have gone through many documentations and tried some of the below mentioned ways

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord gobe throught this article and updated my phpword version to

{
"require": {
"phpoffice/phpword": "v0.18.*"
}
}

$templateProcessor->setImageValue('CompanyLogo', 'path/to/company/logo.png');
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('UserLogo', array('path' => 'path/to/logo.png', 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100, 'ratio' => false));
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('FeatureImage', function () {
// Closure will only be executed if the replacement tag is found in the template

```
return array('path' => SlowFeatureImageGenerator::make(), 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100, 'ratio' => false);
```

});

after all my image is not getting displayed on the word document

can anybody please help me come out of this

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Today I had same error. I think the problem appeared in version 0.18 as in 0.17 it was working.

I did some debugging:

1. Generated a file with 0.17 version (the image was displayed)
2. Generated a file with 0.18 version (the image was missing)

I did unpack both as archive. I noticed that both have the images in the "media" folder.

Also I noticed, that v0.17 package inserted the image twise into document, while v0.18 just once.

So I just duplicated my `->setImageValue(...)` call and that worked. You can try same

Comment: Hi, Can you share code, if possible? please.
I am having same issue and its driving me nuts.